# Why I cannot access last package version?

Tags: pi-3, raspbian-stretch, shared-libraries

if you check here: http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/pool/main/m/mesa/

You will be able to see that all the mesa packages Ej. "libgles2-mesa-dev" have a 18.1 version, however, if I execute the command "sudo apt-get install libgles2-mesa-dev" it says that I'm already on the latest version (13.0.6), I thought this was because I was using a RPi3 with raspbian Jessie, but like an hour ago, I did a fresh install with the last raspbian image (debian 9 strecth), and when I execute the command to install the mesa packages it still points to the 13.0.6 version, so why that version 18.1 exist?, what distro can access it?

PD: before trying to install the library, I ran:

sudo rpi-update
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org) to check this in a really easy way. I usually just search in Google for the package name and look for the result from the Debian Packages site.

Here's [`libgles2-mesa-dev`](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/libgles2-mesa-dev) in the package list. Note that for Stretch, the header is:

> Package: libgles2-mesa-dev (13.0.6-1 and others)

So, in this case, you have the latest version from the *Stretch* repository. If you look in the top right of that page you can also see [stretch-backports] and [buster]. Buster is what will become Debian 10, and is currently in testing, but that is where [18.1.4](https://packages.debian.org/buster/libgles2-mesa-dev) is used. Generally it is a [**very bad idea**](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_make_a_FrankenDebian) to start taking packages from testing and installing them in your stable distribution (it usually ends up breaking your system horribly).

"Stretch Backports" is a more interesting repository though; consisting of fairly up to date packages "backported" to Stretch. If version 17.3.9 was satisfactory you could try [installing from the backports repo](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/).

Comment: You can also get this information from `apt-cache showpkg libgles2-mesa-dev`.  If you use "any" in the Debian search, you can get a list of [all available versions and the release the release they are in](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libgles2-mesa-dev&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all).  This is worth mentioning because there is a 17.3.9-1 in [stretch-backports](https://backports.debian.org/]). But unless you have a good, concrete, important reason to do so, stick with the stable version.

Comment: Also worth mentioning (not everyone is aware of this): Package wise, Raspbian is identical to Debian, from which it is derived.  However, don't use anything from the latter, it won't work!